# Cognos 11 report listing contact phone number

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I am hoping to get some assistance with creating a Cognos report. I have some experience making basic reports but I feel out of my depth here.

The following are the fields I have available:
Contact ID
Phone Type
Phone

Table resembles this:

| Contact ID | Phone Type | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | 1234567890 |
| 1 | H | 1234567890 |
| 2 | M | 1234567890 |
| 2 | H | 1234567890 |
| 3 | H | 1234567890 |
| 3 | W | 1234567890 |

Contact ID and Phone are integers. Phone Type can either be C, H, W, or M for Cell, Home, Work, and Mobile respectively. Contacts don't always have all types listed but can.

What I need:
A two column list, first column is the Contact ID, the second column Phone, with each contact only having 1 row in the report. I need the following priority: C > M > H. I don't want the Work phone at all. So if they have a Cell phone listed, I want that number. If they don't have Cell or Mobile, but have a Home phone listed, I want that number.
Output should look like this, which will be exported in CSV:

```
Contact ID    |   Phone
_____________________________
10292         |   1234567890
102847        |   0987654321
```

I tried doing a Join, with query 2 providing the Cell number and query 3 providing Home.
My Join is structured like this:

```
             Query 2
            |
Query 1  <-- 
            |
             Query 3
```

I then had an IF statement in the Phone data item of the List (query 1) like this:

```
IF ([Query2].[Cell Phone] is not null)
THEN ([Query2].[Cell Phone])
ELSE
IF ([Query3].[Home Phone] is not null)
THEN ([Query3].[Home Phone])
ELSE null
```

I was not able to get the desired results because there are users that do have a Home phone type which are not in the report output. I am not clear on how the cardinality works, so that might have been a part of the issue.
The output I am getting looks right, but when I dig into it, I have found data missing. At least 1 contact that only has a home phone type is not included in the output.

Please let me know if I need to provide any other useful details.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: More detail please.  Your code references Query2 and Query3.  Is this an expression in a UNION query?  What does your query structure look like?  What is the purpose of each query?  Sample data would also be helpful.

Comment: Also, include desired output based on the sample data (input).

Comment: Thank you for responding, @dougp. I updated my post to contain some of what you asked for. I am not sure how to provide you with the input, I am not the manager of the database and I only have access to report studio to create reports that access the data.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about Coalesce. I put that in place because it is cleaner than my nested IF statements. However, the output still does not contain a contact that I know has a home phone number.

Comment: Please clarify in your question what results you are getting and the difference between that and your desired results.

Comment: @dougp I have updated the post again. I am not sure why the table isn't showing correctly, it looks right on the edit post screen.

Comment: You still haven't included what you tried.  "I tried doing a join" but you didn't include any of the properties of the join.

Comment: Basically, consider how you would write the query in SQL.  After all, all Cognos is doing is generating SQL for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you'll want something like this basic SQL:

```
COALESCE([Cell], [Mobile], [Home])
```

`COALESCE()` should work fine in Cognos.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an expression to detect the types that exist
and a case statement to select the desired value to show

For example, create 3 new data items to figure out if an entry exists
This flattens out the results so you can show the id and desired number

Data Item CType

```
If ([Phone Type] = 'C')Then([Phone])else(Null)
```

Data Item MType

```
If ([Phone Type] = 'M')Then([Phone])else(Null)
```

Data Item HType

```
If ([Phone Type] = 'H')Then([Phone])else(Null)
```

Then a coalesce or case statement

```
Coalesce([CType],[MType],[HType])
```

or if you want this would also work

```
case
when ([CType] IS NOT NULL)Then([CType])
when ([MType] IS NOT NULL)Then([MType])
when ([HType] IS NOT NULL)Then([HType])
else(Null)
end
```

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>Phone Type</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>C Phone</td>
<td>M Phone</td>
<td>H Phone</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>C</td><td>5554567890</td><td>5554567890</td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>H</td><td>1114567890</td><td></td><td></td><td>1114567890</td>
</tr>
</table>

For example
```